# eclipse metadata refresh without opening eclipse

Tags: eclipse

We are working with various cloud platform(like. salesforce etc) and we need sync with server everyday. would like to know is there way that we can in our development box to synchronize all eclipse projects through some script without opening the IDE and open the IDE without much freezing.

1. This would enable to do clean sync( with cloud server) and refresh with local files.
2. This would enable to do refresh( for non cloud server ).
3. running a little ant or some kind of script would have development stable unique environment across all developers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to GREATLY depend on what cloud platforms you are using.  HOWEVER, i work with the salesforce platform.  They offer (per their dev. docs) an [ant API jar](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) that allows you to write ant scripts that can essentially check out everything in your org.

Essentially you can use it to check out and check back in pieces and parts of the website.  Though this of course only works for SFDC.  For other platforms you will need to refer to their API's or write your own tools.